# Chinese garbled code occurs when using MELT script

Tags: linux, bash, melt

How can I solve the problem of using the watermark function of the following script to generate Chinese garbled code?
melt link:https://www.mltframework.org/docs/melt/
I searched through the official documents and couldn't find a solution.

The watermark in the upper left corner of the image is garbled in Chinese
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oIVkH.png)

shell script：

#! /bin/bash

/home/eyinhe/playback/temp/Shotcut/Shotcut.app/melt 
-profile hdv_720_25p 
colour:black out=349 length=349 
-track  
test.mp4 in=0 out=249 -blank 0 -attach watermark:"+中文d中文的-1001.txt" 
test1.mp4 in=0 out=100 -blank 0 -attach watermark:"+中文d测试-1002.txt" 
-transition composite:25%/25%:50%x50% in=0 out=349 a_track=0 b_track=1 sliced_composite=1 
-consumer avformat:/home/eyinhe/playback/temp/001.mp4 acodec=aac vcodec=libx264

Comment: Please  [format your code properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: You have a beautiful computer, but what's the point in showing a photograph of it?

Comment: The watermark in the upper left corner is garbled in Chinese

Comment: You still have not formatted the code in your question. Please take a couple of seconds to look at your own posting: In the code you wrote, I can not see where one statement ends and the next one starts.

Comment: @user1934428 I have re edited my question, please take a look again

Comment: Still not good formatting. Code should always be formatted in fixed-space font, not proportional font. I wonder whether you have actully read the link I sent you.